# Cleanup / Prune Unreferenced Data in Dimension Tables

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse, star-schema, percona-toolkit

We have a star schema data warehouse running on MySQL 5.6. We keep a rolling 18 months of data in our fact tables using partitions by month. We have a number of dynamic dimension tables that are referenced by multiple fact tables. However, we have no easy way to remove the rows from dimension tables that are no longer referenced by any fact table. Quick summary looks like this:

```
dim_url - 1B rows - 360GB
fact_ranks - 2.3B rows - 240GB
fact_seen - 2.8B rows - 295GB
```

Currently we are attempting to use a combination of Percona Archiver and triggers to generate "used dimension keys" tables, so we can do the process online. We then use the key table to build a new dimension that only has referenced rows. However, we have been unable to complete this process in production and estimate it could take up to a month.

This has to be a common problem with a more elegant solution.

Comment: I assume the big problem is that a dim row might come back into existence as you are trying to delete it?

Comment: We have triggers set on the fact tables that handle the case of a dimension key being referenced after we have built the used keys table. The main issue is how long it takes to build the used key tables.

Comment: Is it one dimension table, that is bigger than each of the two fact tables? I don't do much DW, but that seems a bit unusual. What attributes does dim_url have?

Answer (score 1):

How about partitioning the dimension tables by a new "last_referenced_date" column (monthly)?

- The column would be set to current date on record INSERT.
- First run of cleanup process would have to chunk through complete fact tables  - and set the value appropriately (MySQL will automatically move data to correct partition).
- Future runs would only have to look at current fact data (most recent month?).
- Then, just drop any partition where the newest date is older than the oldest fact table dates.

Answer (score 0):

(Normally, I would say "don't bother".  But I see that your Dim table is nearly as big as the Fact table.  Hmmmm...  Perhaps it was unwise to even have the Dim table??  Think about that.)

For building the `Used` table (and assuming a Trigger handles incoming Inserts):

From the Fact table, build a list of useful values (`Used`).  Do this one chunk at a time, say, 1000 rows, as determined by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  This list goes into an extra table, `Used`.  One transaction per chunk.  De-dup and add a PK.  See my [*comments on chunking*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).

Now, walk through the Dim table, perhaps only 100 rows at a time, and do a multi-table delete, using `LEFT JOIN Used ... WHERE ... IS NULL` to determine what is not needed.

Be cautious -- the `DELETE` and the `TRIGGER` may step on each other.  That is, there may be deadlocks necessitating re-execution.  But 100 rows at a time should keep that at a nice balance between minimizing deadlocks and maximizing speed.  One transaction per chunk.

Yes, it will take time -- both for the discovery of `Used` and for the `DELETEs`.  But it should not matter.  Everything else is humming along, with only very rare and brief interference.

I guess the `TRIGGER` would need to insert into `Used` when a row is inserted into `Dim`.

Comment: This is pretty much the process we already have in place. However, we don't do DELETEs because they don't recover space in InnoDB. Instead we generate a new dimension using the key table. I'm really looking for an existing hardened utility or some kind of lightbulb.

Comment: In one sense, `DELETEs` _do_ recover space in InnoDB.  They _do_ leave free space in the tablespace that can be re-used by subsequent `INSERTs`.